# Xtext: Scope method not execute?

Tags: scope, xtext, rule, scoping

I've got this IScope method:

```
IScope scope_Assignment(AssignmentOrFBCall a, EReference ref){
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    return IScope.NULLSCOPE;
}
```

but it doesn't produce any results. Nothing in output with println and content assistant does not change. So I thought it hasn't be executed, but if I try to add a breakpoint, it will be crossed.

So, where is the problem?

Grammar rule is this:

```
AssignmentOrFBCall:
    (((variable=[VariableDefinition]) |
    ((variableArray=[ArrayDefinition]'['index=ExpressionIndex']')('.'internalVariable=InternalRecursive)?) | 
    (variableStructOrFB=[VariableDefinition]'.')(internalVariable=InternalRecursive))
    ((':='expression=Expression)|('('(parameter=FBParameter | ')'))))
;
```

Comment: I do not understand: On one hand you say there is no output, on the other hand a breakpoint in the shown method is crossed. This cannot be in a sane setup. If the breakpoint is crossed there has to be _some_ output (event if it is an empty line). Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this scope provider:

```
@Override
    protected IScope createLocalVarScope(IScope parentScope,
            LocalVariableScopeContext scopeContext) {
        if (scopeContext != null && scopeContext.getContext() != null) {
            EObject context = scopeContext.getContext();
            if (context instanceof Program) {
                Program program = (Program) context;
                return Scopes.scopeFor(program.getDeclarations());
            }
        }

        return super.createLocalVarScope(parentScope, scopeContext);
    }
```